# JFileChooser not always opening

Tags: java, netbeans

I've created a class called BasicFile and in its constructer I am setting up a JFileChooser so that the user could choose which file to select themselves. Now it works. But not all the time. Meaning I've ran the program about 50 times and the file selection tool pops out about half the time, the other half the program keeps running (no file selection pops out) and I have to stop the build/run. There is nothing in the call from the test class that would make it act this way (it is just a straight forward call), so I thought it might just be my netbeans glitching up. I restarted my computer, still the same variable results. Help :)

```
public BasicFile()
{
    JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser(".") ;
    int status = choose.showOpenDialog(null) ;

    try
    {
        if(status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) throw new IOException() ;

        f = choose.getSelectedFile() ;

        if(!f.exists()) throw new FileNotFoundException() ; 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        display(e.toString(), "File not found . . . ") ;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        display(e.toString(), "Approved option was not selected." ) ;
    }
}
```

and the call looks like this:

`BasicFile f = new BasicFile() ;`

Comment: Just running your class works everytime on my side. Check if, when it seems to not show properly, it isn't hidden behind another opened window.

Comment: It isn't in the background, but my netbeans has been acting up lately so I think it is just that. For example for some reason when I close netbeans on my Mac, it doesn't fully close, even when I force quit it the netbeans icon on my dock remains lit as if open. So my computer doesn't shut down sometimes since it is still open, and I have to manually press the power button to power down. Do you think deleting it and reinstalling would help?

Comment: I'm not working with a Mac but reinstalling can't hurt... usually :)